# Be + past simple verb

Tags: infinitives, bare-infinitives, active-vs-passive, direct-objects

I was watching a video and I heard the narrator said:
“She had requested his brain be studied”

And I thought it was wrong, but some grammar correctors, like Grammarly, show that this is correct, my question is: Why is that correct?
I think it should be something like: “She had requested his brain to be studied” because request is a verb that needs an infinitive after an object, but then I thought it could be some use of the passive voice or something like that, but I couldn't find any answer.

It would be wonderful if someone can explain it to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't "be + past simple".  It is "be + past participle" and forms the *passive voice.*

In this case, it is also a *subjunctive*. The verb "request" licences a subjunctive complement. The subjunctive is identical in form to a bare infinitive.

Comment: Ohhh, I've heard about the subjunctive mood, so it would be a passive voice in subjunctive mood? I should be “she had requested his brain was studied”?

Comment: Yes, passive voice in the subjunctive mood.  In the active voice "She had requested that someone study his brain".  See https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/subjunctive.htm for more about subjunctive with verbs like "request">

Answer (score 3):

It is a subjunctive mood. The base form of a verb is used in the subjunctive mood. 'Be' is appropriate here.

Active: She requests that *they study his brain*. She requested that *they should study his brain.* She requested that *they study his brain*. She had requested that *they study his brain*.

Passive: He requests that *his brain be studied*. He requested that *his brain be studied.* He requested that *his brain should be studied*. He had requested that ***his brain be studied.***

**[** Active: They study his brain. Passive: His brain *is* studied (by them).

Active: They should study his brain. Passive: His brain should *be* studied (by them)

Active: They studied his brain. Passive: His brain *was* studied (by them). **]**